Toggle the audio permission (not microphone) of a video on a browser when a page loads through JS
I have written a react component, i want that when the page loads, it toggles the browser to ask allow audio and video.
how to do it.
I tried to google but i can only get to toggle microphone and camera, but i want to toggle the audio and video.

what do u mean by audio and video. do u have an example? As far as i know, browser would only ask for microphone access and camera in your case.

If you are using a html <video> element then it's a native element so will automatically be rendered on load. You can add the muted attribute to automatically mute the sound. Otherwise, you would need to have display:none on the element on load and then use a custom modal or native prompt to ask for user input then based on the response show/hide as necessary.
